# Bootstrap DropDown Menu: Remove Scrollbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, scrollbar

I'm working in following [GitHub-Repo](https://github.com/patreu22/Twittex).

When the window width decreases,the navbar collapses and changes to a dropdown menu with scrollbars (for width and heigth).

How can I remove those scrollbars?

I tried adding

```
.navbar-collapse{
max-height:auto;
max-widht:auto;
}
```

to my css file which handles the collapsing size.

Comment: you can use `overflow: hidden`

Answer (score 10):

Another solution is adding the following to your CSS:

```
/* No scrolling for collapsed menu */

.navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: none !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: To get rid of a half-scrollbar that appears after opening and closing the dropdown menu in IE and Edge, use `.navbar-collapse { overflow: hidden !important; }`

Answer (score 2):

Change your css to

```
.navbar-collapse.in {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mXLSk/8/)**

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
.navbar-collapse {
    max-height:100%;
}
```