# Increasing the height of the Bootstrap Collapsed "mobile" navigation menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am struggling to get the mobile collapsed drop down nav to increase in height. Currently it is stuck at about 340px and I need it to expand to fit the menu items being contained within the collapsed nav. I have searched tirelessly on Google and here to find an answer but none of them seem to make an impact, even when I use !important.

Here's a screenshot of what I am talking about to avoid any confusion. **The blue bordered area** that I added to the screenshot is what I am talking about. This seems to be set to a static height and I need it to extend about another 50px-100px for this particular application. I did not show code here because I am hoping to just see the "best way" to change the default height for my future reference.

[image: Drop down nav]

Thanks for the help!
EDIT: I did not submit code because right now it's just the default bootstrap nav code so I didn't think I needed to reference it.

Here's the code, I am just using a simple generic startbootstrap.com template here.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

I have no custom CSS yet as this is the first thing I am trying to change and don't know where in the CSS the dropdown nav should be edited.

[image]

Comment: You would like your dropdown to be bigger right?

Comment: You need to post the code you are working with in a complete, working example (HTML/CSS/JS). [mcve]

Comment: @DianeDuquesne yes, what happens is a scrollbar appears instead of the drop down area expanding to show the data. It's about 50px too short requiring users on mobile to scroll inside the drop down menu to see the last menu item.

Comment: @vanburen I didn't post code because I don't know where this CSS attribute comes from to expand the height of the drop down nav of the bootstrap mobile nav space. I am talking about the actual menu links that appear when you press the hamburger button in bootstrap. That div that opens below the navbar seems to have a set height by Bootstrap default instead of expanding all the way to display the nav links without the user having to scroll.

Comment: Maybe this could answer your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291034/bootstrap-dropdown-menu-remove-scrollbar

Comment: @DianeDuquesne unfortunately that's similar but not the solution. I want the "overflow" to just expand the div the links are inside. The overflow: hidden just ignores any overflowed data and leaves it inaccessible.

Comment: @crescentfresh Did you fnd the solution for this ? I have same scenario

Comment: @Learning I don't remember exactly but in the bootstrap.css file there's a line for I believe .navbar-collapse with a max-height setting. I think you need to overwrite that in your CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code it is difficult to say what is impacting the height. If you add more `<li>`'s to the menu, does it expand?

If not, there could be a static height or max-height css property applied to the `.dropdown-menu`

**Editing for improvement:**

It looks like either of these elements;

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
```

has a `height` or `max-height` and `overflow:auto` property.

Inspect these elements in chrome to see if this is the case. Then, set `height:auto;` and/or adjust the `max-height` property to allow for increased height for that element.

You can set these in your custom CSS file and they will override Bootstrap's style. Just ensure that your CSS file is loaded after the Bootstrap CSS file.

If you can post a link I can look at it and provide the exact code needed to make the changes.

Comment: Added code and another image to show a better example of what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my mobile collapsed drop-down navigation displaying a scrollbar rather than expanding to show all the navigation links. My solution was to hide the scrollbar then add pixels to the bottom of my `data-target` div.

You should be able to hide the scrollbar using:

```
.navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then you can add the extra pixels needed at the bottom by adding padding to the `data-target` div when sized for mobile devices:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-ex1-collapse {
      padding-bottom: 50px;
  }
}
```