# Navbar height auto not working for dropdown menu in mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Nav bar has two dropdown. In mobile view first drop down works fine (height:auto works). But second dropdown is in button group and height of this, not expanded (height:auto doesn't work in this case). My scenario is same as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33425000/increasing-the-height-of-the-bootstrap-collapsed-mobile-navigation-menu). Second dropdown will be created dynamically.So I think that might be the reason for not responding to height:auto.

As you see in the first figure, when I open first drop down, height:auto expands upto max-height 340px. 
[image]
But when I open second dropdown in the same nav, height auto doesn't expand.Here height is only about 122 px
[image]

And the code is,

```
<div class="navbar-collapse in" id="vehicle-group-navbar" style="height: auto;">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown open"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
data-toggle="dropdown">Select Group <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="customerGroups">......</ul>
   </ul>   <!-- first dropdown -->

<!-- second dropdown -->    
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select nav navbar-nav dropdown fit-width label 
    label-info"><button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle plain"
    data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="vehiclesDropdown" title="Select Asset">
    <span class="filter-option pull-left">Select Asset</span><span class="caret">
   </span></span></button><div class="dropdown-menu open"
   style="max-height: 354px; overflow: hidden;">.....</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `style="height:auto"` in your attributes. Did you try to turn off it?

Comment: height:auto works for first drop down. And even when I tried this, `<div class="navbar-collapse in" id="vehicle-group-navbar" style="height: none !important;">` , initially it is in `height:none`. But when I open dropdown, sytle changes to `height:auto` dynamically.

Comment: The attribute height **has no property none**.  Look at the [w3c specification](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_dim_height.asp)

Comment: hmm actually, even if i change height to any fixed value (hegiht: 200px)  when I click navbar icon, it changes to height:auto

Comment: So this is result of JS event "click". Try to find and fix it into your JS file.